# regard C programming code and logic building

Tags: c

Atually i have i understand the code but doesn't understand the logic of the code.I know what is going on but i doesn't know what is happening.The code is of even or odd.The code is.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {    
  int i;

  for(i=1; i<26; i++) {  
    if(i%2==1)        
      printf("%d\n",i);       
  }     

  return 0;
}
```

output:

```
1
3
5
7
9
11
13
15             
17
19
21
23
25.
```

1st repitition:-

```
(i=1;i<26;i++)
 if(i%2==1)
   1%2==1
```

but the result of `1%2` is 0.

I am still getting 1 on my screen. I don't know how I get this '1' , even 1 is 
not equal to 0.

2nd repitition:-

```
(i=1;i<26;i++)
  if(i%2==1)
```

now, at 2nd repition i is 2. AND `(2%2)` is  equal to 0 and 0 is not equal to 1 as follows (0==1) and i am getting 3 on my output screen as i mention above on my screen.

Either I didn't use if condition. how i get this 3 and so on.

Comment: What makes you think that the result of `1%2 == 0`? And we know what your name is; it appears at the bottom right of every single post  you make here, so you don't need to tell us in your question.

Comment: Understanding the code and not understanding the logic is contradictory.

Comment: `%` is the modulo operator. It calculates the remainder resulting from dividing the left side by the right side. So the program only prints numbers for which there is a remainder of 1. It works exactly as it should. And no, "0 is not equal to 1". But `1 % 2` _is_.

Comment: No, you don't get a `2` printed at the second loop iteration, because as you say `2 % 2 == 0`. The `if(i%2==1)` statement ensures you only print the *odd* numbers. The `3` is printed on the *third* iteration, but is only the second item that is printed.

Comment: what  makes me thing 1%2==0? You asked me how it makes me thing.The answer is,it is a basic mathematics when 1\2 it gives nothing but just gives 0.5 as a result and remainder.

Comment: This is *integer arithmetic* which can only handle whole numbers. `1` divided by `2` gives quotient `0` with a remainder `1`.

Comment: I know 0 is not equal to 1.but 1%2 is equal to 0. And as the common sense says by a compiler or in a computer memory. It may appear as 0.JUST like variable memory allocation "I know it is a different thing" i am just trying to tell you the  scenario. i hope you understand

Comment: Please someone tell me that how this whole program works.

Comment: ok ! Now , i thing so right now i want to talk with someone by pointing it out. I am not using the name but i ensures that through the above discussion, to  the person i am pointing to it.Understands clearly.so,integer arithmetic which can handle whole numbers 1divided by 2.gives quotient 0 and remainder 1 is wrong.Actually the scenario is when 1 divided by 2 it gives 0.5 as quotient and 0 as remainder.It is a simple division and basic mathematics as well.

Comment: You clearly don't understand the meaning of the word _integer_. In integer math, 1 divided by 2 produces a quotient of 0 and a remainder of 1. _It just does._ If you don't understand that, it's not a question for Stack Overflow; it's a question for Math.SE _at best_, or perhaps a basic mathematics class. Constantly repeating the results for floating-point division is not going to get you anywhere, seeing as it's completely irrelevant to integer division.

Answer (score 1):

The modulo operator gives your the remainder after integer division. Integer division is different to standard (floating point) division.

```
1/2 = 0.5 (floating point division) 
1\2 = 0 (integer division)
```

### Integer Division

Integer division tells you the total number of times the second number 'fits' inside the first number. It's more obvious with a bigger example:

```
10/3 = 3.333 etc. 
10\3 = 3
```

You cannot fit another entire 3 into 10.

### Modulo (the complement of Integer Division)

Modulo tells you how much space you have left (the remainder). After you put three 3s into 10, you have 1 space left.

```
10%3 = 1 (i.e. 10-3*3)
```

If you used 11 instead of 10, you would have 2 spaces left. If you used 12, you could fit another whole 3 in, leaving no space left.

```
10\3=3 (with 1 space remaining) 
11\3=3 (with 2 spaces remaining) 
12\3=4
13\3=4 (with 1 space remaining)
```

Modulo gives you the amount of space remaining:

```
10%3=1
11%3=2
12%3=0
13%3=1
etc.
```

### Modulo by 2 (to assess even/odd)

In your example, you're doing modulo 2. You cannot fit any whole 2s into 1.

```
1\2=0 (quotient) 
1%2=1 (remainder)
```

So... In your loop:

```
i=1 > 1%2=1 > 1==1 (true) > print 1
i=2 > 2%2=0 > 0==1 (false) > do nothing
i=3 > 3%2=1 > 1==1 (true) > print 3
i=4 > 4%2=0 > 0==1 (true) > do nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Modulus operator `%` in this case returns 0 if the number is even and 1 if the number is odd. So, your code:

```
  for(i=1; i<26; i++) {  
    if(i%2==1)        
    printf("%d\n",i);       
  }
```

checks if the number is odd, and if it is, prints it out. That's the logic behind the modulus operator.

I would suggest in later use to modify this code into:

```
  for(i=1; i<26; i++) {  
    if(i%2!=0)        
    printf("%d\n",i);       
  }
```

to avoid mistakes with negative numbers.

Read [this!](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which part of the comments you didn't understand, but the gist is:

**`1%2` is NOT 0, but 1.**

Either you accept that, and then the program's behavior should be clear, or you don't accept it, and then you did not understand what the `%` operator does. Go and read up on it.